# Basic javascript hide and show image with javascript and flask

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show and hide image on the click of a button, I tested the code in console, everything is working, it is simply the showing and hiding is not working:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="rounded" name="fname" id = "stock_check">
<img id = "my_image" style= "display: hide;" src="{{url_for('static', filename='download.png')}}" alt="greencheck" width="25" height="25"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("stock_check").value;
  if (x === 'W'){
    document.getElementById('my_image').style.display = 'show';
    console.log('if_state');
    console.log(x);
  } 
  else{
    document.getElementById('my_image').style.display = 'hide';
    console.log('else_state');
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `display:none` instead of `hide`.

Comment: I had tried none and had the same problem.

Comment: It should be display:block vs. display:none; instead of show vs hide.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while I was waiting, I thought I would share as I did not see this before.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="rounded" name="fname" id = "stock_check">
<img id = "my_image" style= "visibility:hidden;" src="{{url_for('static', filename='download.png')}}" alt="greencheck" width="25" height="25"/>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("stock_check").value;
  if (x === 'W'){
    document.getElementById('my_image').style.visibility = "visible";
    console.log('if_state');
    console.log(x);
  } 
  else{
    document.getElementById('my_image').style.visibility = "hidden";
    console.log('else_state');
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

I changed the style tovisibility, I think display was giving me issues because I am using an image in flask.

Obviously you don't need the extra console.log(), that was when I was checking if it was the if statement.